# Error occurred in android studio looking for solution

Tags: android-studio

How to get rid of error " can't resolve class SearchView " in XML file of Android studio?

I didn't find any way I searched for it in YouTube didn't find any solution.
Any expert in this field that can solve this problem I will Be THANKFUL.